# Using FluentPostgreSQL in Swift 5.2, POST and GET are working but I have no idea where the data is being stored

Tags: swift, xcode, postgresql, vapor

1) I have the following in Package.swift:

```
    .package(url: 

"https://github.com/vapor/postgresql.git", from: "1.0.0")
 targets: [
        .target(name: "App", dependencies: ["FluentSQLite", "Vapor", "PostgreSQL"]),
... etc.
```

2) And I have PostgreSQL configured in configure.swift:

```
let postgreSQLConfig = PostgreSQLDatabaseConfig(
  hostname: "localhost",
  port: 5432,
  username: "postgres",
  database: "mydb2",
  password: "bigsecret"
)
let psql = PostgreSQLDatabase(config: postgreSQLConfig)
var databases = DatabasesConfig()
databases.add(database: psql, as: .psql)
services.register(databases)
```

3) And I have a table called article in PostgreSQL 11.3.
4) And I have the following in Article.swift:

```
    import Foundation
    import FluentPostgreSQL  
    import Vapor

    struct Article: PostgreSQLModel {
        var id: Int?

        var title: String
        var content: String
        init(id: Int? = nil, title: String, content: String) {
          self.title = title
          self.content = content
        }

    }

extension Article: Content {}
extension Article: Migration {}
```

5) routes.swift looks like:

```
let articleController = ArticleController()
router.get("articles", use: articleController.index)
router.post("articles", use: articleController.create)
```

6) Both the POST and GET are working (i.e. the GET returns everything I've POSTed) ,but I don't see the table in PostgreSQL, so I have no idea where the data is being stored:

```
import Vapor
import Foundation
    final class ArticleController {
        func index(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<[Article]> {
            return Article.query(on: req).all()
        }

        func create(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<Article> {
            return try req.content.decode(Article.self).flatMap { article in
                    print("10j")
                    return article.save(on: req)
            }
        }


    }
```

The
request has Content-Type set to application/json and the request body looks like:

```
{"id":1,"title":"GGG","content":"HHH"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to decode a payload, then save it into database and then transform to desired result

```swift
router.post(at: "article") { req -> EventLoopFuture<String> in
    let article = try req.content.decode(Article.self)
    return article.create(on: req).transform(to: "what happened?")
}
```

If you haven't created a model yet you can do it via migrations in `configure.swift` (example for Vapor3)

```swift
var migrations = MigrationConfig()
migrations.add(model: Article.self, database: .psql)
services.register(migrations)
```

`Artice` model file should look like (example for Vapor3)

```swift
final class Article {
    var id: Int?
    var title: String
    var content: String

    init(id: Int? = nil, title: String, content: String) {
      self.title = title
      self.content = content
    }
}
extension Article: Content {}
extension Article: Migration {}
extension Article: Model {
    typealias Database = PostgreSQLDatabase
    typealias ID = Int
    static var idKey: IDKey { \.id }
}
```

Comment: imike -That built OK but returned 500: {
    "error": true,
    "reason": "`Model.defaultDatabase` is required to use request as `DatabaseConnectable`."
}

Comment: Have you created `Article` model in the database via migration?

Comment: Also it should be conformed to `Model`, please check updated answer one more time

Comment: By the way if you just started with Vapor I'd suggest you to use Vapor4 cause Vapor3 is deprecated already. If you need any assistance I'd love to help in Discord, you could find me there as `iMike#3049`

Comment: try to not to use `save` for record creation, use `create` instead

Comment: OK the migration created an Article table in postgres. I can see it when I do \d. But when I try an SQL query, I get 'Did not find any relation named "Article"'. Like Dracula. You couldn't see him in the mirror.

Comment: Just clone vapor’s `api-template` and take a look how it works https://github.com/vapor/api-template

Comment: Since `Article` is capitalised you need to wrap it in quotes when writing an SQL query

Answer (score 1):

You can't just throw away the future like that. This causes a number of problems:

1. In Vapor 3, that's going to cause a memory leak.
2. You are ignoring the result of the save, so it's failing but you don't know that.
3. You're returning the string before the future - the save in the database - has returned.

Since everything is asynchronous, you need to change the way you write your code. Instead you should do something like:

```swift
router.post(Article.self, at: "article") { req, article -> String in
    return article.save(on: req).map { savedArticle in
        return("what happened?")
    }
}
```

As for why the save has failed, you should see that printed out in the console.

Comment: The question has shifted from "how do I handle a POST request?" to "save() and create() both seem to save an Article and init() returns everything I've POSTED, but I don't see the table inPostgreSQL 11.3"

Answer (score 1):

Mystery solved.
You need to quote the table name because of the capital A:
mydb4=# select * from "Article";

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to mention back in 2) - configure.swift at the end should have the migration code to create the table when you run the Xcode (or migrate any columns you added or changed in Article.swift):

```
var migrations = MigrationConfig()
migrations.add(model: Article.self, database: .psql)
services.register(migrations)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also the POST request body (I'm using Rested on the macbook) should not have a PK (PostgreSQL supplies the PK). So:

```
{"title":"GGG","content":"HHH"}
```

not

```
{"id":1,"title":"GGG","content":"HHH"}
```